# Amazon Cognito AuthFlow

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, amazon-ec2, amazon-cognito

Somewhat of multiple question but,

How does one perform authentication with Amazon Cognito User Pools, in .NET.
I am initiating the Auth with the following:

```
var response1 = client.InitiateAuth(new InitiateAuthRequest()
            {
                AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.USER_SRP_AUTH,
                AuthParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"USERNAME","User" },
                    {"SRP_A"  ,  A }
                },
                ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            });
```

Their documentation is really, really bad, and I can't seem to find what to pass when I want to respond to the challenge.

```
client.RespondToAuthChallenge(new RespondToAuthChallengeRequest()
        {
            ChallengeName = ChallengeNameType.PASSWORD_VERIFIER,
            ChallengeResponses = { /*WHAT am I supposed to add here, and where can I find any documnetation on what is expected?*/ },
            Session =  response1.Session,
            ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        });
```

On a side note, I want to use Cognito Federated Identities to protected a custom .Net API, so my idea is to use a Token returned by Cognito to pass as the JWT to the webapi side, where I would then decode and validate the token. Is this a expected way to use Amazon Cognito for? (I don't want to use amazon API gateway, for now at least).

I am assuming its just configuring OWIN with a default JWT middleware, or should I expected something else?

Comment: Your side note is basically correct: User Pools give you very similar JWT tokens as Google etc..., and are used by Identity Pools in the same way.

Comment: Regarding SRP, [it's a standard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol), but I've not yet gotten it working in C# against Cognito.

Comment: "Their documentation is really, really bad, and I can't seem to find what to pass when I want to respond to the challenge.". I agree. It is very, very very detailed on how cognito works but no clear road map or example on how to use it in .net. Very frustrating! I often found myself trying to duplicate the steps the docs lay out only to give up. I found out recently that what I was trying to duplicate was a description of what is happening behind the scenes and not at all what I needed to do to USE it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html) touches on what needs to go into the request for both initiate auth and respond to auth challenge.

You will likely find it easier to offload the srp authentication to Cognito with the AdminInitiateAuth API (detailed in the same link), which will fill in these blanks for you.

The mobile SDKs have wrappers around SRP authentication for you, which help fill in these parameters, but other SDKs have no such features in place. You could use the code for the SDKs (all of which live in GitHub) to fill in things like SRP_A, but you'll likely find it far easier to just use AdminInitiateAuth.

Comment: `AdminInitiateAuth` does not "offload the srp authentication" - hence the flow name `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH`. SRP is the algorithm that avoids sending the password across the wire, so using `AdminInitiateAuth` is strictly less secure, though it's basically what every other login page on the internet does. Basically it's intended for server side use.

Comment: It does offload it. The cognito servers do the srp on your behalf, but to do so it needs username and password to serve as the de facto client. The docs may not be terribly clear on this, as your inference is fair, but it does offload. Source: I'm on the cognito team

Comment: The idea behind the name was that you don't have to do the SRP, that it looks like every login page on the internet, but in the background it uses the same backend store, doing so by leveraging SRP.

Comment: I stand corrected! Thinking about it you would internally need to do *some of* the SRP calculations to verify the password the way it's stored, but is it really doing all the HTTP requests too? That seems weird.

Answer (score 0):

This guy here describes how to do the SRP calculations in a .NET app. I had to add some logic to update the temp passwords issued when creating users in console, but other than that it works like a charm

[AWS Cognito SRP Login in C# / .NET](http://blog.mmlac.com/aws-cognito-srp-login-c-sharp-dot-net/)

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of using `RespondToAuthChallengeAsync`'s `ChallengeResponses`

```
var RespondToAuthChallengeRequest = new RespondToAuthChallengeRequest
{
    ChallengeName = ChallengeNameType.PASSWORD_VERIFIER,
    ClientId = "appClientId",
    ChallengeResponses = new Dictionary<string, string>
       {
           { "USERNAME", username },
           { "NEW_PASSWORD", password }
       },
    Session = response1.Session
};

var respondToAuthChallengeResponse = await client
        .RespondToAuthChallengeAsync(respondToAuthChallengeRequest);
```